# AWS CDK check if resource exists

Tags: aws-cdk

I want to do the following in a (Python) cdk project:

- test if a specific security group (of which I know the name) exists in the target account.
- if it exists, add an ingress rule to one of my security groups allowing traffic from the looked up group
- if it does not exist, don't add the ingress rule but deploy the remaining stack

For this to work, I need to somehow find out if the security group exists. I tried to run a `lookup` on it and catch potential errors:

```
try:
  sg = ec2.SecurityGroup.from_lookup_by_name(
            self,
            "SG",
            vpc=vpc,
            security_group_name="mysg",
        )
except:
  sg = None
```

But CDK does not seem to throw errors this way, and errors out ignoring my try/except clause. Because if I do `cdk deploy` or `cdk synth` I get:

> [Error at /stack/TestIngress] No security groups found matching {"account":"...","region":"eu-central-1","securityGroupName":"mysg","vpcId":"...","lookupRoleArn":"..."}

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: could you add some information to the question?
Is the indentation correct in your original script?!  try and except must have the same indentation...
which is the error message? it happened while running 'cdk deploy' or 'cdk synth' ?

Comment: sorry for the wrong code! I fixed it and added some more info